# vectors on an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, orthogonal

how are you? I need help. I read an image and then display it, then click two points on the image say: *p1* and *p2*. Now I want to draw lines (arrows if possible) showing that these are vectors orthogonal to the ground plane. Then draw lines parallel to the y-axis and each of these points say *l1* and *l2* and finally calculate the shortest distance between these lines. I have gotten the points, drawn the lines but am not sure how to get the distance. Also I have observed that for one line it works fine but for two lines, they are drawn in different locations, I dont know why. I have been trying to do this for about three days but the results I get are far different from what I want. As for some parts am not sure how to do it. Below is the code I have currently. I have also attached an image demonstrating what am trying to achieve. I hope its understandable. I removed the part where I try to get the distance because even if I know that I need four points from these lines to estimate the shortest distance between them, I don't know how to get these points :( - am open to suggestions.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks for the help. PS. let me know if what am trying to do is impossible. It seemed logical to me though when i set out to do it.

Below is my current code

```
% Read and display image
i = imread('sample.jpg');
im = i;
f = figure;
imshow(im);
% Get user clicked points
[p1 p2] = getpts(f);
% Draw parallel vertical lines at given pts. parallel to the y-axis/post
hold on;
line([p1(1) p1(1)], get(gca, 'ylim'));
line([p2(1) p2(1)], get(gca, 'ylim'));

% Calculate shortest distance between these two lines 
% - not sure how to proceed with this because as far as i know I need at
% least 4 points to determine where they meet :(


% Draw vector symbols at points
% 1. draw x component arrow/line - parallel to the x-axis of image 
% (or perpendicular to y-axis??) but must be perpendicular to ground plane
  % Slope of current line
    m = (diff(p1)/diff(get(gca, 'ylim')));
    % Slope of new line
    Li = 10 ;
    minv = -1/m;
    line([mean(p1) mean(p1)+Li],[mean(get(gca, 'ylim')) mean(get(gca, 'ylim'))+Li*minv],'Color','r')
% 2. draw y component arrow/line - parallel to the y-axis of image
    % Slope of current line
    m = (diff(p2)/diff(get(gca, 'ylim')));
    % Slope of new line
    Li = 10 ;
    minv = -1/m;
    line([mean(p2) mean(p2)+Li],[mean(get(gca, 'ylim')) mean(get(gca, 'ylim'))+Li*minv],'Color','k')
axis equal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the documentation of getpts, it returns [X,Y], with Point_i=[X(i), Y(i)].

Since the two lines are parallel in your case, they do not intersect and d is therefore the x difference of the two selected points. Or was this just a special case?

A first draft would look like this:

```
% Read and display image
i = imread('Sample.jpg');
im = i;
f = figure;
imshow(im);
% Get user clicked points
[X, Y] = getpts(f);
% Draw parallel vertical lines at given pts. parallel to the y-axis/post
hold on;
line([X(1) X(1)], get(gca, 'ylim'));
line([X(2) X(2)], get(gca, 'ylim'));

d=X(2)-X(1);
```

For the rest of the code, please be more specific. Since you want to show the normal vector of the picture, do you want to plot the whole thing in a 3D plot?

EDIT: Regarding the comments, the final code has been modified to show a 2D image in a 3D plot. Further imporvement can be done, but should be rather easy (e.g. have a look at [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12274-3d-arrow-with-many-color-parameter-options) or [this](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7470-plot-2d-3d-vector-with-arrow) for arrows)

```
% Read and display image
myImg = imread('Sample.jpg');
f1 = figure;
imshow(myImg);
imSize=size(myImg);
% Get user clicked points
[X, Y] = getpts(f1);
xLim=get(gca, 'xlim');
yLim=get(gca, 'ylim');
close(f1);

% Draw parallel vertical lines at given pts. parallel to the y-axis/post in the image
lWidth = 5; %width of line in Pixel, should be odd
lColor = [255,0,0]; %Linecolor in RGB
pColor = [0,255,0]; %Pointcolor in RGB
vColor = [0,0,255]; %Vectorcolor in RGB

% image positions of points in pixel
xP1=int16((X(1)-xLim(1))/(xLim(2)-xLim(1))*imSize(2));
xP2=int16((X(2)-xLim(1))/(xLim(2)-xLim(1))*imSize(2));
yP1=int16((Y(1)-yLim(1))/(yLim(2)-yLim(1))*imSize(1));
yP2=int16((Y(2)-yLim(1))/(yLim(2)-yLim(1))*imSize(1));

% Draw lines in image
for xLine = [xP1,xP2]
    for i = max([1,xLine-(lWidth-1)/2]):min([imSize(2),xLine+(lWidth-1)/2])
        for j=1:imSize(1)
            myImg(j,i,1:3)=lColor;
        end
    end
end

%mark Points
Points=[[xP1,yP1];[xP2,yP2]];
for k = 1:2
    Pos=Points(k,:);
    for i = max([1,Pos(1)-(lWidth-1)/2]):min([imSize(2),Pos(1)+(lWidth-1)/2])
        for j = max([1,Pos(2)-(lWidth-1)/2]):min([imSize(1),Pos(2)+(lWidth-1)/2])
            myImg(j,i,1:3)=pColor;
        end
    end
end

%3D plot - Some rotations required to get a nice axisvalue alignment
g = hgtransform('Matrix',makehgtform('translate',[0,imSize(1),0])*makehgtform('axisrotate',[0,1,0],pi)*makehgtform('zrotate',pi));
f2 = image(g,myImg);
axis([0,imSize(2),0,imSize(1),-0.1,1.1]) %axis range
view(40,30) %view point

%add normal vectors
hold on
r=(lWidth-1)/2;
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(r);
xC1=X+double(xP1);
xC2=X+double(xP2);
yC1=imSize(1)-Y-double(yP1);
yC2=imSize(1)-Y-double(yP2);
mesh(xC1,yC1,Z,'facecolor',vColor/255,'edgecolor',vColor/255);
mesh(xC2,yC2,Z,'facecolor',vColor/255,'edgecolor',vColor/255);
```

Comment: I prefer to have it as simple as possible. if it is possible to have it in 2D, then I prefer 2D. Otherwise if 3D won't be so troublesome. Then thats even more interesting. 
As for the distance, I was confused on how to determine the two closest points of the two line segments. Because I assume that that would be the shortest distance between the lines.

Comment: mhm, that explains why it worked for one line but not for two separate lines, thanks.

Comment: Actually if it wont be too much work 3D makes more sense, in which case the lines will have to parallel to the y-axis of the ground plane. Brilliant idea.

Comment: which matlab version are you using, `f2 = image(g,myImg);` is giving an incorrect number of arguments error.

Comment: thanks I guess I fixed it. But quick question, how to just view it in 2D plot.

Comment: clear all code below and including %3D plot ... and replace it with a simple imshow(myImg)

Comment: thanks, but i just noticed something. you forgot about the horizontal component of the vectors. we only got the orthogonal ones/vertical ones :(.

Comment: you mean the shortest connection between the two lines? you can add it as `imshow(myImg); hold on; line([X(1),X(2)],[(Y(1)+Y(2))/2,(Y(1)+Y(2))/2]);` in the 2D image

Comment: no no, for each point, there is an orthogonal normal (vertial component of the vector), now the other is the x-component. The ones with arrows on them.

Comment: like this? `imshow(myImg); hold on; line([X(1),X(1)+xLim/10],[Y(1),Y(1)]); line([X(2),X(2)+xLim/10],[Y(2),Y(2)]);`

Comment: thats throwing errors. did you mean something like `xLim(1) ... xLim(2)`? `xLim(2)` is ok but `xLim(1)` is off. its not at the marked point. and Yes something like that :)

Comment: oh sorry, didnt test the code. thi should work `imshow(myImg); hold on; line([X(1),X(1)+(xLim(2)-xLim(1))/10],[Y(1),Y(1)]); line([X(2),X(2)+(xLim(2)-xLim(1))/10],[Y(2),Y(2)]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162660/discussion-between-gordon-and-hth).